# data type with read.xlsx in R

Tags: r, r-xlsx

I am using `xlsx` library in R to read a excel sheet. I used the following command. My data are numeric/floats with `NA`  for missing values and first column as name (string/character type). However, all the column are of type `character` and I could not find if I can somehow specify `NA` values as missing values. Any suggestions on how to deal with the issue?

```
df=read.xlsx(file0, sheetName = 'sheet1', as.data.frame = TRUE, 
             header = TRUE, use.value.labels=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Would it be acceptable to remove NAs as a second step?: `df[df=='NA'] <- NA` followed by: `df <- sapply(df, as.numeric)`

Comment: you may consider using `read_excel` from `readxl` which has an option to specify `NA`.

Comment: My first thought was 'but doesn't `read.xlsx` have an NA option?', but didn't see it in the documentation. Of course it was `read_excel`. Not mad Hadley et al. came and fixed things, but it does make it hard to keep things straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try

```
df[]=lapply(df,type.convert,as.is=TRUE)
```

`type.convert` will attempt to find the appropriate class of each column and convert accordingly. Without the option `as.is=TRUE` it will convert the `character` columns to factors.
It also handles `NA` strings. The default option `na.strings="NA"` should be ok for you.